# "Move To" Command Deleted My Files?

Tags: boot, usb

Have a USB Flash Drive that has worked in the past every time I use it.  Today, I tried to copy some files over to it, so I plugged it in, the computer recognized it.  I opened it in on the desktop, but when I tried to drag my files over, it gave me an error message about "input/output error".  So, I selected my files, and right clicked and selected "Move to....", and selected my target folder on the USB drive.  I clicked "move", and then the USB window popped back up like it had rebooted, and my files are gone!  They are not in the original directory, nor are they on the USB drive!  I've tried to locate them with ls -a to recover them with mv .... [name] but they don't show up.  Please help!  Thanks so much for any assistance.

Comment: Few times I encountered similar problem, I was unable to restore files, but the answer to your question would interest me.

Comment: Follow up-  I've run several "find" searches for them, searched all through my tmp files, trash, recent files, and can come up with nothing.  What happened?

Comment: Simply - they have been cut, but not pasted. It should be fail-safe, but obviously is not. Let's wait for the answer.

Comment: I don't suppose it put them in /media/kit/ did it? You may need a file recovery tool such as `foremost` to get the originals back?